# SignalR encrypt QueryString parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, encryption, signalr, signalr-hub

I am using `SignalR` on a `Asp.net Web Api` project.

I am connecting to the hubs from separate `Asp.net MVC` projects.

Everything works fine until now.

However, i need to implement Authentication on the `SignalR Hubs`, in order to do this, i simply need a `token` to be send as QueryString parameter:

```
// Hub implementation on Asp.Net Web Api project
public class AppHub : Hub
{
    public override async Task OnConnected()
    {
        string token = Context.QueryString["token"];
        var validateResult = ValidateRequestService.ValidateToken(token);

        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, validateResult.UserName);

        base.OnConnected();
    }
}

// Javascript implementation on Asp.net MVC project
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://webApiProject.com/signalr';
$.connection.hub.qs = { 'token': '@(ViewBag.SessionToken)' };
```

This works.

The problem is that i store sensitive information (`token`) on the client (browser). If a hacker inspects the source code of the page, it can easily see the `token` key.

Is there any way to encrypt / decrypt the query string parameter so it will be encrypted on the client side?

I can easily encrypt it on the client, but the problem is that it will be sent encrypted to the `Web Api` server as well.

Would an `HttpModule` work in this case?

Comment: SignalR supports the built in model in ASP.NET use that

Comment: @Anders I am not using `FormsAuthentication`. The `token` is validated using an external service

Comment: Use a custom membership provider and let ASP.NET marshal the authenticaton for you edit: btw, you are not limited to Forms, you can use Windows too

Comment: The Web Api server with the SignalR has no clue about membership at all. It can only validate requests using a third party service (via an Http request) - i cannot use Membership

Comment: You can use a CUSTOM membership provder, that way you outsource the client / server security part to ASP.NET and do not need to worry about if your solution is secure.

Comment: Can you give me a link, reference, or show me an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

To implement a custom memebership provider implement *System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider*

Example from one of my projects

```
public class MembershipProvider : System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider
    {

        ...

        public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
            return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserManager>().ValidateUser(username, password);
        }
    }
```

If you need roles implement role provider *System.Web.Security.RoleProvider*

```
public class RoleProvider : System.Web.Security.RoleProvider
    {    
        ...

        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            var user = dependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserManager>().GetUserBy(username);
            return user.Roles.Select(r => r.Name).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

All other methods can be left unimplemented for basic functionality

In the web config do

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
  <providers>
    <remove name="AspNetSqlProvider" />
    <add name="MyProvider" type="MyApp.Web.Common.Membership.MembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MyRoleProvider" applicationName="/" type="MyApp.Web.Common.Membership.RoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

You can then login like Forms auth was enabled for example

```
[HttpPost]
public bool Login([FromBody]CredentialsViewModel credentials)
{
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(credentials.Username, credentials.Password))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(credentials.Username, credentials.Remember);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```